# When run "sonar-runer" throw exception :"Caused by: Unknown database status: FRESH_INSTALL"

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

I need help

First , it throw exception

> cannot load class 'com.mysql.xxx.JDBC'",so I copy the
>   sonarqube-4.0/extensions/jdbc-driver/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar
>   to the /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-sun/jre/lib/ext/

Then I run `sonar-runner` again, it throws this exception:

> Unknown database status: FRESH_INSTALL

My heart is broken , plz help me

Comment: There is nothing wrong in sonar.log

Comment: This is the last log in sonar.log:2013.11.11 16:02:35 INFO  Web server is started

Comment: When I check mysql database sonar , do "show tables" ,there is nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this error when the database is empty (no tables are created). Usually tables are created during first start of sonar.

Can you reach sonar by web interface?

Make sure that settings in your `conf/sonar.properties` file in `Sonar` directory are correct, these lines should be uncommented.

```
sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
sonar.jdbc.username:                       mysqlusername
sonar.jdbc.password:                       mysqlpassword
```

Then check if your `conf/sonar-runner.properties` file in `sonar-runer` directory has the same settings.

```
#----- MySQL
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8

#----- Global database settings
sonar.jdbc.username=mysqlusername
sonar.jdbc.password=mysqlpassword
```

Also make sure that the line for default embeded database is commented.

```
#sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
```

Comment: Thank u very much. It just is the problem , I use default config file

Answer (score 0):

Sonar stopped supporting the property "sonar.jdbc.schema" from 4.2 version. Please refer link http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5000. To fix the issue on PostgreSQL based sonar deployment, execute the following SQL command on the database:

ALTER USER $dbUser$ SET search_path to $soanrQubeSchema$

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem, and I solved it by restarting sonar server after creating  proper  user and database in mysql.
In fact, sonar server will fill the empty mysql database with many tables after restarting, and that removed the "FRESH_INSTALL" problem.